# NHibernate many-to-one fetching same item many times

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

In my model I have Games. Each Game has an Event associated with it, which is mapped as a many-to-one association.

When I query for Games, within event with given EventId (different than its DB-PrimaryKey-id) NHibernate issues the following query for each and every Game:

```
NHibernate: SELECT event0_.Id as Id8_0_, event0_.EventId as EventId8_0_ FROM Events event0_ WHERE event0_.EventId=@p0; @p0 = '4'
```

In my mapping (and in the DB generated from the mapping) EventId has a Unique constraint. How do I tell NHibernate that it should fetch the Event only once for given EventId, not issue the same exact query N times for N Games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was that foreign key was set on non-primary key of the 'one' table. Changing that fixed the issue.